# How can web requests be made and go undetected by a packet sniffer tool like Charles?

Tags: macos, cocoa, ssl, proxy, packet-sniffers

I am using a third party (OS X) tool to help me process OFX financial data. It works, but I am interested in knowing what exactly is going on behind the scenes to make it work (the structure of the HTTP requests).

I setup Charles as an SSL proxy for all traffic in hopes that I could observe the requests being made by this tool, but the program runs and Charles gets nothing. No requests show up whatsoever. How is that possible? Is there something I am not understanding about how Charles or other packet sniffing tools work? What are some ways that web requests could be made that wouldn't show up in a tool like Charles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Charles is not a packet sniffer. It's a proxy. The app initiating the connection has to "voluntarily" use the proxy for the proxy to see anything. If an app uses a high-level networking API like `NSURLConnection` then it will, by virtue of the frameworks, automatically pick up the system-wide proxy settings and use the proxy. If, instead, the app wrote their networking using low-level socket API, then they will not end up going through the proxy unless they specifically re-implement that functionality.

If you want to see *everything*, you will need a real promiscuous-mode packet sniffer, which Charles is not. Unfortunately, using a "real" packet sniffer will just show you the gibberish going over the wire for SSL connections, so that's probably not what you want either. If an app has "in-housed" its SSL implementation and is not using a properly configured system-wide proxy, sniffing its traffic unencrypted will be considerably harder (you'll probably have to use a debugger or some other runtime hooking approach.)